# MVC - Change Compare attribute error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In my MVC application I have the ability to get the error message from a text file instead of using the default error message.  This works perfectly on the Required attribute (both Serverside and Clientside).

I now need to do the same with the **Compare** attribute, but I can't figure out how to override the Compare attribute.

For reference, this is how I am doing it with the Required attribute (I would like similar code to this to work with the **Compare** attribute)...

```
Public Class RequiredFieldAttribute
    Inherits ValidationAttribute
    Implements IClientValidatable

    Private innerAttribute As New RequiredAttribute()
    Private errormessagecontrolid As String

    Public Sub New(ErrorMessageControlID As String)

        Me.errormessagecontrolid = ErrorMessageControlID

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function IsValid(value As Object, validationContext As ValidationContext) As ValidationResult

        If Not innerAttribute.IsValid(value) Then
            Return New ValidationResult(ErrorMsgs.Text(Me.errormessagecontrolid))
        End If

        Return ValidationResult.Success

    End Function

    Public Function GetClientValidationRules(metadata As ModelMetadata, context As ControllerContext) As IEnumerable(Of ModelClientValidationRule) Implements IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules

        Dim result = New List(Of ModelClientValidationRule)

        Dim rule = New ModelClientValidationRule() With {.ErrorMessage = ErrorMsgs.Text(Me.errormessagecontrolid), .ValidationType = "required"}

        result.Add(rule)

        Return result

    End Function

End Class
```

Above, ErrorMsgs.Text is the function that retieves the message from the text file.  Against my model I then apply something like this...

```
<RequiredField("AccountDetailsPostcodeError")>
Public Property PostCode As String
```

The system then looks in the Text file for an entry called AccountDetailsPostcodeError.

How can I achieve the same with the Compare attribute.  At the moment I have a hard coded error message like this...

```
    <Compare("WebPassword", ErrorMessage:="The password and confirmation do not match.")>
    Public Property ConfirmWebPassword As String
```

**Edit**: The suggested fix below may work in C#, but won't work in VB.NET, hence my more complex requirement to override the Compare attribute.  I just don't know how to correctly override it.

Comment: Why create a textfile in which the lookups take place? Why not use the resource files like it is meant to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why use a text file for your translations and messages, .NET has build in options for translations. You can use resources. The advantage of using resources is that resources are type safe, they are checked as compile time. Where your textfile can become corrupt / missing.

The following guide helps you with setting up resources in a Mvc project:

### Step one

Edit the default assembly language:

- (C#) Properties > Assembly information > Neutral Language
- (VB) My Project > Assembly information > Neutral Language

Set this language to your default language. (For this example I use `English (United States)`)

### Step two

Add a resource file to your project. Call this file `Resource.resx`. Open this file. Change the Access Modifier to `Public` and start adding resource strings. For example:
[image: Default English resources]

### Step three

Add for each other language you want to support another resource file but name them `Resource.LANGUAGE.resx` where LANGUAGE is replaced by the other culture name. For culture names you can check this url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Then fill the new resource file with the localized strings. For example:
[image: English Resources]

### Step four

Then you can in your Models use the default localization support of the attributes:

For example:

#### VB:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Public Class UserModel
    <Display(Name:="UserNameField", ResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessageResourceName:="RequiredUsername", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Display(Name:="PasswordField", ResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    <MinLength(6, ErrorMessageResourceName:="PasswordLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    <Compare("PasswordAgain", ErrorMessageResourceName:="CompareError", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessageResourceName:="RequiredPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    Public Property Password As String

    <Display(Name:="PasswordAgainField", ResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessageResourceName:="RequiredPasswordAgain", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(My.Resources.Resource))>
    Public Property PasswordAgain As String
End Class
```

#### C#

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class UserModel
{
    [Display(Name = "UserNameField", ResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = False, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredUsername", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    public string UserName;

    [Display(Name = "PasswordField", ResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    [Compare("PasswordAgain", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CompareError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = False, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    public string Password;

    [Display(Name = "PasswordAgainField", ResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = False, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredPasswordAgain", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(My.Resources.Resource))]
    public string PasswordAgain;
}
```

For localization the attribute needs to know the name of the static property and the type of the static class where to get the property from (as seen above).

### Step five

Then in your view use the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to get all the error messages, or use

- **VB** `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Property)`
- **C#** `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property)`

to get specific error messages.

For the display attribute you can use:

- **VB** `@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Property)`
- **C#** `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Property)`

---

### Changing the language

And last but not least you can change the language of your app instead of your neutral language defined in step one by editing the `Web.config` and changing the globalization tag like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="nl" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you want to change the language from code you should edit `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` for information about this I suggest google or another SO question.

---

#### Example project

For this question I quickly made an example project to provide an accurate answer. Project can be found here:
[MvcVBTest.V1.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DEB5DDFF6A505390!433)

---

## UPDATE

If you don't want to use Resources but a single text file you can use the same concept the resource framework uses. You need a class that has static properties you can reference.

For this purpose I did the following things:

1. I created a class called `Resources` (Resources.vb).
2. In this class I added a sub class called `Resource`
3. In the static constructor of this class I open `resource.xml` which I have mapped to an array of `Resource`
4. This array is then converted to an `Dictionary(Of String, String)`
5. I created an static get property for every item in the xml. And returned the right item from the Dictionary
6. I changed the `ResourceType` parameter in the `UserModel` class

And of course a little clean up. The old resources can be deleted and the `globalization` tag can be removed from the `web.config`.

Now all the text can be found in `resource.xml` as key value pairs. To add another line, add it to the XML and create a property for it in the `Resource` class.

#### Example project

For this update I updated my example project:
[MvcVBTest.V2.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DEB5DDFF6A505390!434)

Comment: While I appreciate the effort of this reply, I was using a text file for a reason.  We look after websites for dozens of customers.  Every customer has their own look and feel for their website, we create the CSS and we can also customise the text on the webpages.  So customer one may want "Password and confirmation do not match", customer two may want "Please make sure the password match".  If your solution could work based on say a setting from the web.config (e.g. TextTheme=Customer1) instead of the culture this would be perfect, but can it?

Comment: @cw_dev added an example that uses an XML file that you can edit.

Comment: @cw_dev and please stop using Visual Basic, it is plain ass irritating to work with :P this answer took me more effort than I would like to admit, pure because I first had to think it up in C# and translate the code to VB

Comment: Perfect solution. It's a pity you can't read directly from the XML file without the need for the Properties, but this a great solution for my needs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this?

```
<RequiredField(ErrorMessage=GetErrorMessage())>
```

Just create a static function that gets the error message for you. You can even take a parameter for your GetErrorMessage function so you can determine which message you'll want to return.

Comment: Should this work in VB.NET?  If I try similar to what you have mentioned I get "Constant Expression is required"

Comment: I'm not sure for VB but i use this in my model when using C#. There it works fine. But i guess there sould be a similar solution for this in VB?

Comment: I'd have thought a solution was possible but can't figure it.  The VB.NET equivelent of Static is Shared but this won't work.

Comment: how about first putting it in a string variable and then using that string in the ErrorMessage=stringVariable   ?

Comment: Like:- Dim ErrorMsg As String = "Error here" and then <Compare("Email", ErrorMessage:=ErrorMsg)> ?  This didn't work either.  Must be a VB.NET thing.