# String.Format multi lingual not working

Tags: c#, localization

The following is how I am using String.Format to display message :

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CommonResource.AlreadyExists, PageResource.UserViewModel_EmailId, viewModel.EmailId)
```

Sweedish string for AlreadyExists is `{0} '{1}' Redan Finns`
English string for AlreadyExists is `{0} '{1}' already exists`

But message is always displayed in English. Even if I select Swedish as the language.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.

1. `String.Format` uses the culture parameter to get the right culture resource.
2. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is the right culture.

To address those:

1. `String.Format` uses culture to format `DateTime` and number objects.
2. 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' is the culture info that windows uses to format `DateTime` and numbers. If you want to get your Windows UI culture you need to use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`.

`CommonResource.AlreadyExists` should already return the Sweedish string if your windows culture is set to Sweedish. If not, you might have set the resource files wrong.

See those of my answers for more on Resources and cultures:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352010/637425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529046/637425

Comment: But String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CommonResource.Invalid, PageResource.UserViewModel_EmailId). This is working fine. The only difference is I am not concatinating any runtime value here.